# What js framework is using in Storify for user interface development?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, drag-and-drop

Im very interested in Storify's editor user interface, how can do Drag and Drop effect like the Stority's editor?

Answer (score 1):

Looking through their loaded javascript libraries, it looks like they are relying on jquery and the jquery UI plugins, especially draggable / droppable:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/